# React Typescript, AntD Reusable form not working for more then one field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

```
import { Form, FormInstance } from 'antd';

interface FormPropsType<T> {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    onFinish: (data: T) => void;
    layout?: 'horizontal' | 'vertical' | 'inline';
    form?: FormInstance<T>;
}
const ReusableForm = <T,>({ children, onFinish, layout, form }: FormPropsType<T>) => {
    const handleFinish = (formData: T) => {
        onFinish(formData);
        console.log('finish called!!!');
        formInstance.resetFields();
    };

    const [formInstance] = Form.useForm<T>(form);

    return (
        <Form form={formInstance} onFinish={handleFinish} layout={layout} requiredMark="optional">
            {children}
        </Form>
    );
};

export default ReusableForm;
```

```
import { Col, Form, Input, Row } from 'antd';
import { Rule } from 'antd/lib/form';

interface FormFieldProps<T> {
    name: string | string[];
    label?: string;
    rules?: Rule[];
    value?: string | number | readonly string[];
    onChange?: (value: T[keyof T]) => void;
    placeholder?: string;
}

const ReusableFormField = <T,>({ name, label, rules, value, onChange, placeholder }: FormFieldProps<T>) => {
    return (
        <Row gutter={16}>
            <Col style={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex' }}>
                <Form.Item name={name} label={label} rules={rules} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                    <Input value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange?.(e.target.value as T[keyof T])} placeholder={placeholder} />
                </Form.Item>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    );
};

export default ReusableFormField;
```

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';

import ReusableTable from './ReusableDatatable';
import ReusableForm from './ReusableForm';
import ReusableFormField from './ReusableInput';
import ReusableModal from './ReusableModal';
import { handleEdit } from './tableHandlers';

const UsersComponent: FC = () => {
    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

    const handleCreateUser = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(true);
    };
    const handleModalClose = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };
    const columns = [
        { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', key: 'name' },
        { title: 'Age', dataIndex: 'age', key: 'age' },
        { title: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', key: 'email' },
    ];

    const data = [
        { key: '1', name: 'John Doe', age: 30, email: 'john@example.com' },
        { key: '2', name: 'Jane Doe', age: 25, email: 'jane@example.com' },
    ];

    const onFinish = (values: any) => {
        console.log(values);
        // handleModalClose();
    };

    return (
        <>
            <ReusableTable
                columns={columns}
                data={data}
                onEdit={(record) => {
                    handleEdit('user', record);
                }}
                createButton={{ text: 'Create User', action: handleCreateUser }}
            />
            <ReusableModal open={isModalVisible} title="Create User" onClose={handleModalClose}>
                <ReusableForm onFinish={onFinish} layout="horizontal">
                    <ReusableFormField name="category" label="Category" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter the category' }]} />
                    <ReusableFormField name="username" label="Username" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'username field can not be empty' }]} />
                </ReusableForm>
            </ReusableModal>
        </>
    );
};

export default UsersComponent;
```

I'm using AntD in my project. I need form in my different pages. to avoid code duplication i tried to make form and its fields reusable. when i used this form with only single field, it works correctly. validating as it should and All of my code is working .
But as i added more than one fields to the form, it is not working. The point i notices after a lot of console logs is that , in my ReusableForm component ' handleFinish' function is not getting invocked on submission.
i don'nt know what's going on here. Please help to resolve the issue.
A big thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remember antd forms correctly, you shouldn’t be manually passing a value and onChange to your Input as props in your ReusableFormInput. FormField does that under the hood for you, your job is to just pass FormField a child that accepts a value and onChange, but not pass the props directly yourself. Indeed, you aren’t passing these props in the places you call ReusableFormInput anyway. Does it work if you remove value and onChange from your Input in ReusableFormField?

Comment: ok. i removed these props. but still facing the same issue. 'handleFinish' not working for more than one fields. but only for one field.

Comment: There's something else going wrong with your code, a [simplified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nuyh8z?file=package.json,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2FUsersComponent.tsx,src%2FReusableFormField.tsx,src%2FReusableForm.tsx,src%2FApp.css,src%2Findex.css,src%2Fmain.tsx&terminal=dev) shows your stuff works correctly. The problem isn't in the form components.